# PDF of squared random variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, density-function

i have complex gaussian random variable given as  $h\sim\mathcal{C}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2})$. And i had $Y = |h|^{2}$. So what should be pdf of $Y$. I understood that $Y$ is exponential random variable, and so it's PDF should be of exponential random variable. But what should be the expression of PDF of $Y$. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: add the self-study tag, also try to describe more about how much do you understand about $Y$ is exponential random variable?